# SystemJS and Firebase

Tags: firebase, systemjs

I'm trying to use Firebase with Angular 2, SystemJS and Typescript. I have the following file hierarchy:

```
_ www
|_ app
 |_ etc...
|_ lib
 |_ @angular
 |_ firebase
  |_ app.js
  |_ auth.js
  |_ firebase.js
  |_ firebase-auth.js
  |_ etc...
 |_ rxjs
 |_ etc...
 |_ index.html
 |_ systemjs.config.js
```

When I want to use Firebase, I import Firebase in my typescript source as follows:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
```

To load the Firebase module I include the following `systemjs.config.js` script in `index.html`:

```
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        paths: {
            "lib:": 'lib/'
        },
        map: {
            // angular & rxjs refs go here...
            'firebase': 'lib:firebase'
        },
        packages: {
            // other package references go here...
            firebase: {
                main: 'firebase.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
})(this);
```

However, any attempt to use any of the functions defined in `firebase.js` (e.g. `firebase.initializeApp`) gives an exception telling me that the function is not a function (e.g. `firebase.initializeApp is not a function`).

If I change Firebase's `main` reference in `systemjs.config.js` from `firebase.js` to `app.js`, then I can use the function `firebase.initializeApp` without any errors.

Closer inspection of `app.js` and `firebase.js` show they have slightly different construction (I'm not a js expert), i.e., `app.js`

```
var firebase = (function(){
var firebase = null; (function()...
// more js here
... return firebase;}).call(global);
module.exports = firebase;
```

and `firebase.js`

```
var firebase = null; (function() {...
// more js here
... ();}).call(this);
```

So why does `app.js` work, and `firbase.js` not work? What do I have to do to get `firebase.js` to work?

Comment: This appears to be a problem with using SystemJS and the latest firebase release. See [SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41171210/angular-2-and-firebase-sdk)