# Angular 2 and Firebase SDK

Tags: angular, firebase, systemjs

I've been trying to get the Angular2 [quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) app to work with Firebase (see this [repository](https://github.com/jdbriaris/Quickstart)). I've installed the latest version of Firebase, attempted to load firebase using SystemJS (see [systemjs.config.js](https://github.com/jdbriaris/Quickstart/blob/master/systemjs.config.js)) and tried importing firebase and using the function `initializeApp` (see [app.component.ts](https://github.com/jdbriaris/Quickstart/blob/master/app/app.component.ts)). However, I keep getting the error `firebase.initializeApp is not a function` in the browser console. Am I using SystemJS correctly to load `firebase.js`?

*Note*: To replicate the error, you should just be able to do `npm install` followed by `npm start`.

Comment: I had problems with Firebase and SystemJS when preparing a Plunker for an AngularFire2 issue. I had to use version 3.4.0. In later versions, there is something in the TypeScript definitions that SystemJS just does not like, but I didn't look into it.

Comment: @cartant: Yes, reverting to version 3.4.0 seems to fix the problem with SystemJS. The respective `firebase.js` files appear to have changed between version 3.4 and 3.5. Later versions (>3.4) appear to have all the javascript in `firebase.js` and no module exports. Whereas v3.4 simply 'requires' other files and exports module 'firebase'. I've got a feeling it's to do with the lack of module exports in later versions, but not entirley sure.

Comment: @artem: D'oh! That's when you know you've been staring at the screen for too long... Fortunately only a test bed - phew. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Removed my dependency on SystemJS and switched to Webpack. No problems loading `firebase.js` and using it with Webpack.

Answer (score 5):

One change: from

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
```

to

```
import {firebase} from 'firebase';
```

is enough to make your example work with firebase 3.6.

However, I'd say it's working by accident. `firebase.js` does not look like a module at all, it does not use `module.exports` or amd `define`, it just creates global variable `firebase` with the following properties:

```
INTERNAL: Object
Promise: Promise()
SDK_VERSION: "3.6.4"
User: (a, b, c)
__esModule: true
app: a(a)
apps: (...)
get apps: ()
auth: (c)
database: (c)
default: Object
initializeApp: (a, c)
messaging: (c)
storage: (c)
__proto__: Object
```

Probably, it's the presence of `__esModule` that makes SystemJS to wrap it in another object - if you look in the debugger at the result of `import * as firebase from 'firebase'` it contains single property also named `firebase` which is the actual module that you need.

Interestingly, the `firebase.d.ts` is written in such a way that

```
import {firebase} from 'firebase'; 

firebase.initializeApp(...);
```

works, but seemingly equvalent

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

firebase.firebase.initializeApp(...);
```

does not typecheck.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround for this issue [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/576#issuecomment-266797842) and, with it, I was able to get a plunk working with the latest versions of Firebase (3.6.7) and AngularFire2 (2.0.0-beta.7).

How it works, I have no idea, as I only use SystemJS with Plunker, but it involves replacing this:

```
firebase: {
    main: 'firebase.js'
}
```

with this:

```
firebase: {
    defaultExtension: 'js',
    main: './firebase-browser.js'
}
```

in the `packages` property of the configuration that's passed to `System.config`.